# Docker container exiting on MacOs?

Tags: python, docker

I built a docker image from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.4-slim-jessie

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install -U flask
RUN pip install networkx

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "flask_vis.py" ]
```

It pretty much just downloads the required packages for a flask app (flask_vis.py). When the container is run, the app should run.

Here are the relevant lines of flask_vis.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

print("Reading pickles...")
start = time.time()


edges_df=pd.read_pickle("edges_table.pkl")
print("done with 1")
nodes_df=pd.read_pickle("nodes_table_all_labelled.pkl")
print("done with 2")
ev_df=pd.read_pickle("evidence.pkl")
print("done with 3")
print(f"Took {round(time.time() - start, 3)}s to load pickles.")

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges_df, edge_attr=True, source="source_id", target="target_id", create_using=nx.DiGraph())


@app.route('/', methods=["POST","GET"])
def home():
    if request.method=="POST":
        query_type=request.form["query_type"]
        if query_type=="Query with Dijkstra's algorithm":
            query_type="dijkstra"
            return redirect(url_for("validate", query_type=query_type))
        else:
            query_type="single"
            return redirect(url_for("validate", query_type=query_type))
    else:
        return render_template("home.html")
```

I built the container with `docker build --tag appname .`
When I ran it with `docker run -t -p 5001:5001 appname` the console would print "Reading pickles", "done with 1", and "done with 2." However, the container would exit before it read the third pickle. This happens when I run the container on a mac, but it works on windows. Why does this happen? Is there any way I could make it also work on mac?

Comment: What does the `docker logs` output look like?

Comment: They are blank; there aren't any errors